# how to start/stop a Timer/AsyncTask in an android view

Tags: android, asynchronous, view

I need a job which is to be executed at a fixed time(for example every 1 seconds).

I know I can implement this by the `Timer` or the `AsyncTask`.

However I have to start the job when the view is created. But I wonder where I can stop this job?  Since I have not found a lifecycle for `android.view.View`.

What is the alternative solution?

---

I have a custom view which can be used by others, and I have to start a `Timer` or an `AsyncTask` once the view is focused, and stop the background job when the view is invisible.

Comment: What type of Application is it?  Why do you need to know the "life-cycle" of a certain `View`?  Do you mean an `Activity`?

Comment: I do not mean the `Activity`. Because I create a timer on the constructor of my custom view, and I have to stop it when the view is disposed.

Comment: So the `Activity` will continue to run, but the `View` will be destroyed?  What type of `View` is this?  How is it displayed.  Explain your program.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `activity` has View instance, call a method of `View` to let know view class that activity is destroyed or stopped, depending on your requirement.

```
private View mView;
public void onDestroy {
    super.onDestroy();
    mView.stopCounter();
}

public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mView.stopCounter();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
     void doInBackground(..)
     {
        do
        {
           Thread.sleep(1000);
           //Your Work
        }while(condition);
      }
}
```

If you want to stop the activity return a boolean value to onPostExecute and stop the work what you were doing.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the methods you can Override.

`onWindowVisibilityChanged` and `onWindowFocusChanged` look helpful.

```
@Override
protected void onWindowVisibilityChanged(int visibility)
{
    super.onWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility);

    switch(visibility)
    {
        case VISIBLE: /* code */ break;

        case INVISIBLE: /* code */ break;

        case GONE: /* code */ break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
}
```